# List with explicit mixed types in Dart

Tags: dart, types

Is there a way of defining a List in Dart with mixed types, while explicitly setting the types of each element?

I know there is a Tuple type that does this, but I was hoping there is a way of doing it with the built-in List type.

(Right now my way of doing so is using a `List<dynamic>` or a `List<Object>`)

Example of what I'm looking for:

```dart
final mixedList = <bool, String>[false, 'Hello'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

That thing *is* a tuple, not a list (sequence of similarly typed values).

If you could create a `<bool, String>[false, 'Hello']` *list*, then the type of `list[0]` and `list[1]` depends on the *value* of the index.
That breaks static typing, since it's a kind of dependent typing (the type of an expression depends on the value of another).